# How to determine what font an X application needs

Tags: fonts, xorg

I'm trying to run an application over an X server and I'm getting the following message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  45 (X_OpenFont)
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  9
```

As far as I understand from everything I've read this means the computer I'm trying to display on is missing a font. Trouble is, I don't know what font's missing. The above message is the only message being displayed.

How do I determine what font is missing?

Follow up:

I changed the DISPLAY variable to localhost:... and watched the packets go by with wireshark. It looks like the name of the font being requested is "*". Is there a problem with this request? It would seem to me that this would just load any font. Is there a problem with my font configuration?

More follow up:

I've confirmed on the working machine that it is also requesting the "*" font. I know this because I'm trapping the calls to XLoadFont with gdb and the name parameter is coming up as "*".

What is supposed to happen in this case? Is it supposed to return literally *any* font?

Comment: Really relevant question ! In a standard situation a tool should declare its font dependencies properly in its GNU/Linux distribution specific package description. To fix such a trouble, most users seem to apply a guess-and-try font package installation loop until the tool no longer complains...

Comment: You're telling me there's no tool to query what fonts an application is using? I have a system that it does work on, so if there were some way to figure out what fonts it's using, that would work for me.

Comment: So you may install all font packages from your working system. Or you may use "ltrace" to get handle on libX11 calls and probably find the font name passed to "X_OpenFont" method...

Comment: @YvesMartin Can you comment on what's supposed to happen wrt requesting the "*" font?

Comment: If other applications work properly I guess your fonts are OK. What is `xlsfonts` output ? Is it possible to know what application is in trouble on your system ?

Comment: You should compare your systems font list with `fc-list` and maybe rebuild cache with `fc-cache -fv`

Answer (score 1):

According to [XLoadFont](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/font-metrics/XLoadFont.html) documentation, a query with `'*'` should return any matching `Font`.

`ltrace` dumps calls to libraries into `stderr`. If you compare `ltrace` outputs for a correct and a failed execution, you should guess what font has been used from the working system.

An option is also to compare output of `xlsfonts` and `fc-list` commands. In case of doubt, invoking `fc-cache -fv` may help if the cache has been corrupted.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention it here. The issue was that on gentoo the font.alias files have this "comment" at the start that goes "! $Xorg: fonts.alias,v 1.3 2000/08/21 16:42:31 coskrey Exp $". Either that's not a valid comment (my guess), or it's not being treated as a comment. I take that line out and it all works. Thanks for the help though, your trick of ltrace got me to think of gdb, which is how I figured out it was "*".

Comment: So in your case, I guess `xlsfonts` and `fc-list` would have failed with a relevant error message, right ? If so, I guess you may accept my answer as a proper way to diagnose the issue you reported

Comment: No, `xlsfonts` doesn't exist on my machine and `fc-list` doesn't seem to show any error as far as I can tell. It just prints a tone of "filesnames: information".